# LOOPING LISTS of Lists

Tags: python

I need some help to loop over a list of lists .   I am still learning Python.

I have a list of integers  and those integers are a  list of more integers.

Example:

```
itemWalmart= "food","bread"
itemCostco= "furniture","electronics"
superMarket= walmart,costco
```

I need to make a loop listing the  items +  superMarket.Name , My problem is when we add more Super markets and more items to the list.

I want to make a loop so it does it even if the list grows , so it goes through each one.

example of list bigger:

```
itemWalmart= "food","bread"
itemCostco= "furniture","electronics"
itemSoriana= "milk","chocolate"
superMarket= itemWalmart,itemCostco,itemSoriana
```

WHAT I WAS TRYING IT WAS:

```
itemWalmart= "food","bread"
itemCostco= "furniture","electronics"
superMarket= itemWalmart,itemCostco

print superMarket

for i in superMarket:
    print i + superMarket
```

I GET THIS:

```
# (('food', 'bread'), ('furniture', 'electronics'))
# ('food', 'bread', ('food', 'bread'), ('furniture', 'electronics'))
# ('furniture', 'electronics', ('food', 'bread'), ('furniture', 'electronics'))
```

AND I WANT TO GET THIS:

```
"food","bread" , itemWalmart
"furniture","electronics" , itemCostco
```

THANKS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have an easier time using a [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

```
markets = {}

markets['Walmart'] = "food","bread"
markets['Costco'] = "furniture","electronics"

for k,v in markets.iteritems():  #use items if you are using python 3x
    print k,v
```

Comment: seems better suited to that to me as well ... but it should be pretty "easy" either way ...

Answer (score 1):

```
itemWalmart= "food","bread"
itemCostco= "furniture","electronics"
superMarketItems= itemWalmart,itemCostco
superMarketNames = "walmart","costco"

for items,name in zip(superMarketItems,superMarketNames):
  print "Items:",items," Found@",name
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't do this with lists. `itemWalmart` is a variable name, and isn't strongly attached to the variable. (and not retrievable, especially since it has been copied over to `i`).

I suggest using a dictionary:

```
markets={}
markets['walmart']=('food','bread')
markets['costco']='furniture,electronics'

for key,value in markets.iteritems():
   print (key,value)
```

---

If you really want to use lists, then store the market name with the list.

```
itemWalmart= "food","bread","itemWalmart"
itemCostco= "furniture","electronics","itemCostco"
superMarket= itemWalmart,itemCostco

print superMarket

for i in superMarket:
    print i
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this will work but try this, and I dont know python but I think this logic will work

for i in superMarket:
    for x in superMarket[i]:
      print superMarket[i][x]
   print superMarket

Im not sure how to add the " in python for echoing